# Error when use${gl} or ${PWD} for mounting bind volumes in docker run command in PowerShell 7

Tags: windows, docker, powershell-v7

When I try to mount a bind volume using PowerShell 7.4.1, for example with this command:

```
docker run --rm -d --mount type=bind,target=/usr/share/nginx/html,source=${pwd}\docs nginx
```

The command not works and show this message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: ${pwd}\docs%!(EXTRA string=is not
> a valid Windows path).

But if I try the same sentence in PowerShell 5.1 the sentence works.

Does anybody known the reason of this behavoiur?